# How to pass middleware to specified routes in express node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I have a middleware (gateMan) that checks if user is logged in, i don't want the middleware (gateMan) to fire on all routes. However, it would be fired on 98% of my routes, how can i achieve this without calling the middleware on each of the route.

**Middleware**

```
const gateMan = (req,res,next)=>{
    if(req.user)
        next();
    else{
        res.redirect('/auth/login');
        res.end();
    }
};
```

**Route sample**

```
app.use('/',staticRoute);
app.use('/auth',authRoute);
app.use('/user',gateMan,userRoute);
app.use('/mocks',gateMan,mockRoute);
app.use('/sample2',sample2Route);
app.use('/sample3',sample3Route);
app.use('/sample4',sample4Route);
```

I want to apply **gateMan** to all routes except **staticRoute** and **authRoute**. I'm thinking if there is a way i can just pass all routes into and array and apply the middleware to them, how possible is this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use express's `app.use`in your app file. As `app.use` relies on order, you can define your staticRoute and authRoute first, then your middlewares and then your other routes.

```
app.use('/',staticRoute);
app.use('/auth',authRoute);
app.use(gateMan)
app.use('/user',userRoute);
app.use('/mocks',mockRoute);
app.use('/sample2',sample2Route);
app.use('/sample3',sample3Route);
app.use('/sample4',sample4Route);
```

Every route you define after your `gateman` middleware will use that middleware.

Comment: This will cause some problems if `next()` is called in either the `staticRoute` or `authRoute` since the `next()` middleware would be `gateMan`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `app.all('*')` and check inside what `path` is used. From there you can use the logic what's now in the `middleware`. It is a pretty dynamic solution and you don't have to tell which routes are there.

Something like this (not tested though):

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.path !== '/' || req.path !== '/auth') {
        if(req.user)
            next()
        else {
            res.redirect('/auth/login')
            res.end()
        }
    }
})
```

You could then put all unauthorized paths in an `array` and check in `app.all` if the `path` is in that `array`.

Something like:

```
var unauthorizedPaths = [ '/', '/auth']

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if(unauthorizedPaths.indexOf(req.path) === -1) {
        if(req.user)
            next()
        else {
            res.redirect('/auth/login')
            res.end()
        }
    }
})
```

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.all